# Add dictionary key as label if Pandas column contains any value from dictionary values

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a dataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'products' : ['a,b,c', 'a,c', 'b,d','a,b,c']})

    products
0   a,b,c
1   a,c
2   b,d
3   a,b,c
```

And I have created a dictionary that maps specific products to a certain category:

```
mydict = {'good':['a'],'bad':['d'],'neutral':['b','c','a']}
```

I'm trying to create a new column, let's say `df['quality']` that adds the dictionary key (product category), if any of the products in `df['products']` are included in the values for that particular key.
Namely, the final output should look like so:

```
    products quality
0   a,b,c     good, neutral   
1   a,c       good, neutral
2   b,d       neutral, bad
3   a,b,c     good, neutral
```

Any idea? Am I overcomplicating the problem?

Comment: `a` is both 'good' and 'neutral' is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, the same product can be classified in different categories. In that case I would need to add each of the categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first generate a reversed dictionary that maps categories to products, e.g. `a -> [good, neutral]`. Then split the values in `df` over `,`, `explode` them and `map` them with this reversed dict. Then gather them back with `groupby` and `set` over the flattened list products where lastly they are joined with `,` :

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

# form the dictionary
reversed_dict = defaultdict(list)
[reversed_dict[cat].append(prod) for prod, categs in mydict.items()
                                 for cat in categs]

# apply over the df
df["quality"] = (df.products
                   .str.split(",")
                   .explode()
                   .map(reversed_dict)
                   .groupby(level=0)
                   .agg(lambda s: ", ".join(set(chain.from_iterable(s)))))
```

to get

```
>>> df

  products        quality
0    a,b,c  good, neutral
1      a,c  good, neutral
2      b,d   bad, neutral
3    a,b,c  good, neutral
```

Comment: You probably could've done a `defaultdict(set)` then just used `','.join(set.union(*s))` instead of needing the additional import. I'm not sure about runtime though....

Answer (score 2):

Let us try

```
help = pd.Series(mydict).explode().reset_index().groupby(0)['index'].agg(','.join)

df['quality'] = df.products.replace(help,regex=True).str.split(',').map(set).str.join(',')
Out[150]: 
0    good,neutral
1    good,neutral
2     bad,neutral
3    good,neutral
Name: products, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

you should define mydict like this:

```
mydict = {'a': ['good', 'neutral'],
          'b': ['neutral'],
          'c': ['neutral'],
          'd': ['bad']}
```

then:

```
def func(row):
    categories = []
    for item in row['products'].split(','):
        categories = categories + mydict[item]
    return ','.join(sorted(list(set(categories))))

    
df['quality'] = df.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
```

returns:

```
    products    quality
0   a,b,c       good,neutral
1   a,c         good,neutral
2   b,d         bad,neutral
3   a,b,c       good,neutral
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

```
d = {'a': ['good', 'neutral'],
          'b': ['neutral'],
          'c': ['neutral'],
          'd': ['bad']}

df['quality'] = df['products'].str.split(',').explode().map(d).explode().groupby(level=0).unique().str.join(',')
```

or (first part converts the current dictionary to the new format)

```
s = df['products'].str.split(',').explode()

d = {i:[] for i in set(s)}

for k,v in mydict.items():
    for i in v:
        d.get(i).append(k)

s.map(d).map(set).groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: set.union(*x)).str.join(',')
```